# Installing Laravel homestead on a virtual machine in windows 10 - after I created a VM box do I need to install virtualbox again within this box?

Tags: laravel, virtualbox, homestead

Trying to install laravel homestead in windows but inside a virtualbox. So first I installed VirtualBox which then allows me to install a VM which I called LaravelBox (so this is an empty machine) - which means I need to install ubuntu 16.04, then vagrant (as the documents on the laravel homestead site (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead#installation-and-setup) - which instruct me to install the homestead vagrant box, then configure, etc. When I get to he final step to run vagrant up, I get the error:

```
**Vagrant could not detect VirtualBox! Make sure VirtualBox is properly installed.
```

Vagrant uses the `VBoxManage` binary that ships with VirtualBox, and requires
this to be available on the PATH. If VirtualBox is installed, please find the
`VBoxManage` binary and add it to the PATH environmental variable.**

Does this mean then I now need to install virtualbox inside the VM I just created called LaravelBox? - so it's the case of a VM that contains the laravel homestead vagrant box is inside a a VM? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: is your VM a linux distribution or windows?

Comment: Yes my VM is ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

The first question why you try to install homestead in a VM instead of installing it in Windows directly?
Yes, the problem is that your VM can't find any Virtualbox installation, then you have to install it there and it will be working.

Comment: yes I suspect this to be the case, thanks very much. I have setup a working environment for xamp and didn't want the laravel homestead setup to mess it up.

Comment: No, having xamp installed in your windows machine with homestead, will never cause any problem. I suggest for you to install homestead in your windows machine, because doing that in VM doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Virtualbox will not work INSIDE another Virtual Machine. The problem is you're on a 64 bit host operating system that is virtualiz-ing another 64 bit operating system. That 64 bit VM cannot virtualize another 64 bit OS, it would only be able to virtualize a 32 bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

Homestead was meant to provide a Unix like dev environment so that it would be easier to work with symlinks and permissions, it uses Ubuntu vagrant box by default.

So you can either install homestead directly on your host machine i.e windows or as you already have a Ubuntu VM you can setup a basic dev server manually.

It does not make sense to run a VM inside a VM